# how to get current user id zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm trying to get the current user using `indexAction()` function in My controller. I get this error message:

> Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create
>   an instance for zfcUserIdentity

I'm using this statement to get the current user id:

```
$id =(int) $this->zfcUserIdentity()->getid() ;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

zfcUserIdentity is a view helper not a controller plugin. Instead try this:

```
$this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getIdentity();
```

This will get the currently logged in user if any.
If you want to check if a user is logged in use this:

```
if ($this->zfcUserAuthentication()->hasIdentity())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$id = $this->UserAuthentication()->getIdentity()->getId();
```